# There are three checks in this position?

Tags: check, perft

I found [this position](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Perft_Results#Position_2) in the Chess Programming Wiki. It's a perft calculation. In the depth 2 the results informs that there are 3 checks. But I just able to find 2 checks:

- 1. Kf1 hxg2+
- 1. Kf1 Bxe2+

.

```
[FEN "r3k2r/p1ppqpb1/bn2pnp1/3PN3/1p2P3/2N2Q1p/PPPBBPPP/R3K2R w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Where is the third check?

May look stupid, but I really can't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Kd1 Bxe2+ looks like it is another depth 2 check

Comment: Jesus!!! I'm feeling a complete idiot. Thank you!